# How to add arbitrary numbers of DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following

```
# df1, df2, final_df have same index
final_df = ...
df1 = ...
df2 = ...
sum_cols = ['a', 'b', 'c']
final_df[sum_cols] = df1[sum_cols] + df2[sum_cols]
```

Now I want to do this for arbitrary number of dfs

```
final_df = ...
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, ...] # they all have same index
final_df[sum_cols] = df1[sum_cols] + df2[sum_cols] + df3[sum_cols] + ...
```

How do I do this nicely, without a for loop?

Comment: why are you avoiding a for loop? i dont see how that affects performance, if that is what you are worried about. Anyways, it would be easier if you shared some sample dataframes with expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reduce (or you can use a for loop).

```
import functools
import operator

sum_cols = ['a', 'b', 'c']
dataframes = [...] # list of dataframes
final_df[sum_cols] = functools.reduce(operator.add, [d[sum_cols] for d in dataframes])
```

Reduce has the advantage over `sum()` that it doesn't use an initial value (which is `0` by default for sum).

Just using a loop might also be ok and short to write. And efficient, we don't create needless other objects or intermediates.

```
final_df[sum_cols] = dataframes[0][sum_cols]
for d in dataframes[1:]:
    final_df[sum_cols] += d[sum_cols]
```

You could even try to do this in just pandas operations. But I would **not** recommend this. We're just wasting time by copying data at this point:

```
final_df[sum_cols] = pd.concat([d[sum_cols] for d in dataframes], axis=1, keys=range(len(dataframes))).sum(level=1, axis=1)
```

`pd.concat` has an option `copy=False` but in practice it doesn't save copying in most cases.

The alternatives are provided so that it will become easier to be content.. with one of them, maybe just a loop? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sum()` function

```
final_df[sum_cols] = sum(dfs)
```

If the dfs are all numbers

Comment: I would add `[sum_cols]` to keep the same number of columns: `final_df[sum_cols] = sum(dfs)[sum_cols]`

Comment: Probably need to slice each df before calling sum, to avoid problems with column types and to avoid doing needless work